# Insert string after match in variable

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to make some workaround to solve a problem.

We have a gtk+ program that call a bash script who calls rdesktop.
In a machine, we discover that the rdesktop call need on extra parameter...
Since i didnt write anything of this code, and i can modify the GTK part of the problem, i can only edit the bash script that make the middle call between the calls.

i have a variable called CMD with something that look like:

```
rdesktop -x m -r disk:USBDISK=/media -r disk:user=/home/user/ -r printer:HP_Officejet_Pro_8600 -a 16 -u -p -d -g 80% 192.168.0.5
```

i need to "live edit" this line for when the printer parameter exists, it append ="MS Publisher Imagesetter" after the printer name.

The best i accompplish so far is

```
ladb@luisdesk ~ $ input="rdesktop -x m -r disk:USBDISK=/media -r disk:user=/home/user/ -r printer:HP_Officejet_Pro_8600 -a 16 -u -p -d -g 80% 192.168.0.5"
ladb@luisdesk ~ $ echo $input | sed s/'printer:.*a /=\"MS Publisher Imagesetter\" '/
```

Which return me:

```
rdesktop -x m -r disk:USBDISK=/media -r disk:user=/home/user/ -r ="MS Publisher Imagesetter" 16 -u -p -d -g 80% 192.168.0.5
```

Almost this, but i need to append the string, not replace it.

help?

Edit: i pasted incomplete exemples. fixed

Edit2:
With the help of who respond, i end up with

```
echo "$input" | sed 's/\(printer:\)\([^ ]*\)/\1\2="MS Publisher Imagesetter"/'
```

Comment: Use capture groups `()` like `'/\(printer:.*\)/\1=\"MS Publisher Imagesetter\" /'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the output to look like: 
rdesktop -x m -r disk:USBDISK=/media -r disk:user=/home/user/ -r printer:"HP_Officejet_Pro_8600 MS Publisher Imagesetter" -a 16 -u -p -d -g 80% 192.168.0.5

This sed will do, it matches the printer: part first then the existing printer name and quotes both, if not you can adjust the replacement 
variables to put the quotes/spacing where you want:

`input="rdesktop -x m -r disk:USBDISK=/media -r disk:user=/home/user/ -r printer:HP_Officejet_Pro_8600 -a 16 -u -p -d -g 80% 192.168.0.5"`

```
echo "$input" | sed 's/\(printer:\)\([^ ]*\)/\1"\2 MS Publisher Imagesetter"/'
```

output:

`rdesktop -x m -r disk:USBDISK=/media -r disk:user=/home/user/ -r printer:"HP_Officejet_Pro_8600 MS Publisher Imagesetter" -a 16 -u -p -d -g 80% 192.168.0.5`

Comment: Acctualy, what should be insert is ="MS Publisher Imagesetter" after the printer name, but now is just a matter of reorder the \2 :)
THX!!

Comment: @Techmago This actually is too complicated. You don't need the capturing groups, check my answer again. It is doing the same - without capturing groups .

Comment: @Techmago Yea that should do. It is flexible to know how to use hold patterns to manipulate text, in this case you can also probably simplify it more if you want - to something like:  `echo "$input" | sed 's/printer:[^ ]*/"=MS Publisher Imagesetter"/'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
sed 's/printer:[^=]\+=/\0 "MS Publisher Imagesetter"/' <<< "$input"
```

The `\0` in the replacement pattern outputs the match itself.

Comment: The appended string should be after printer:something="MS Publisher Imagesetter"
if i could just put in the end of line, wold be a lot esier (echo ${input}"random text")

Comment: @Techmago Ok, got it. I edited my answer. It should work now .

Comment: there is a missing { ?

Comment: Oh yes it was a typo. Sorry, changed that

Comment: input="rdesktop -x m -r disk:USBDISK=/media -r disk:user=/home/user/ -r printer:random_hp -a 16 -u -p -d -g 80% 192.168.0.5"
ladb@luisdesk ~ $ echo $input | sed 's/printer:[^=]\+=/\0 "MS Publisher Imagesetter\"/'
rdesktop -x m -r disk:USBDISK=/media -r disk:user=/home/user/ -r printer:random_hp -a 16 -u -p -d -g 80% 192.168.0.5